# Quit main loop maybe the thread is still running

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, crash

Hi all~ I have a problem boring me so much.
Sometimes when I exit my program, there are some thread still running, in Linux system, it will cause crash after I quit the main loop. Is there any method that can kill all threads when I quit main loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help a lot if you specified your programming language and threading library of choice.

The usual way to control this type of situation (that is for a parent thread to wait until children complete before terminating) is to call a function supplied by the library, usually named *join* or *wait*.

pthread supplies you with [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html), for example.

If you're spawning processes via fork, you should use wait or waitpid in the parent to halt until the child completes - try man waitpid or take a look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid).

This way you can inform your children that you are about to exit via the usual means, wait until they wrap up and terminate, then cleanly exit the main loop.

Does this help? This is the least brutal way of synchronizing termination, if you want to actively kill the children threads there are alternatives, of course (like pthread_kill for pthreads, for example).

Comment: Thx for your answer, I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java try using the jconsole (Java Monitoring & Management Console) shipped with jdk6u23 in my case. You can get the thread name that is not killed. You can use join for that thread to complete.

But there can be program issue like, in my case i had a timer thread hanging [Timer-0] java.util.Timer to make an a timer.cancel() which closed that timer.